# how to use android actionbar to change contentsView

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I just can't figure out how to make the actionbar work the way I want it to. I would like to click an item on my action bar that changes between the setContentView to different XML files.

I have the following XML files:
activity_main_vertical_view.xml
activity_main.xml

(Note that this is not so that I can see it in landscape mode, I'm aware of making a folder called layer-land. I want my xml file to be viewable horizontally in portrait mode which is why I'm trying to change XML).

I have a "change view" item in my actionbar which I'd like to make XMLs switch when I use it. However it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

I have 2 classes:
MainActivity.java
VerticalView.java

My Manifest.xml has the following code with respect to VerticalView

```
<activity
    android:name=".VerticalView"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_vertical_view" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.calendar.activity_main" />
</activity>
```

My Menu for activity_main.xml has the following code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/change_view"
    android:onClick="changeView"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/change_view" >
</item>
```

my MainActivity.java has the following code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void changeView(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), VerticalView.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Finally, my VerticalView.java has the following code:

```
public class VerticalView extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_vertical_view);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not follow the rules for `android:onClick`:

> The method must be declared in the activity as public and accept a MenuItem as its only parameter, which indicates the item clicked.

Your method takes a `View` as a parameter, not a `MenuItem`.

Also note that this approach only works in API Level 11 and higher. For backwards compatibility, you may wish to skip `android:onClick` and override `onOptionsItemSelected()` instead.

Comment: Looks like I must have missed the documentation for Menu and went straight to actionbar. Adding this link for noobs he need this answered better. Thanks CommonsWare
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479992/handling-a-menu-item-click-event-android