# Using a icon button in actionbar to navigate to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am having an issue as to how to code in my activity to actually implement a onClick event to go from that activity to my HomePage. What should I add to my mainactivity in order to implement a onclick to go to another activity?

[image]

searchmenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home2"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

Activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);

    final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_home:

            startActivity(new Intent(AuctionList.this,SignIn.class));
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have look [this](https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-options-menu-example-using-getmenuinflater-inflate-oncreateoptionsmenu-and-onoptionsitemselected)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling a Menu Item Click Event - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479992/handling-a-menu-item-click-event-android)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_home:

                // Do menu item stuff here
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jianminmong.aucon/com.example.jianminmong.aucon.SignIn}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: @saapmong please add stacktrace and update your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
this code used in activity..

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);
return true;
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_home:

            // Do menu item stuff here
            return true;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

below code used in fragment..

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
    inflater?.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu) // define menu file name
}
```

// click event handle

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    when (item!!.itemId) {
        R.id.mnSearchProduct -> {
          // call your fragment.
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
```

Comment: i having error.not sure why.its not in the activity,its error in the activity i want to go to.